# Implement Keyword driven testing framework selenium in protractor

Tags: angularjs, selenium, protractor

Right now I am using a **keyword driven framework with selenium webdriver + Test NG** where i am putting all my test cases in a excel file(keyword driven) and reading that and then executing that as Test NG .
Now I want to use all that testcases written in excel (Keyword driven ) using **protractor** so i dont have to recreate all test cases.
Can anyone  please suggest that its is possible as protractor is run on node server??

Comment: its very much possible. i am working on very similar product

Comment: Please provide the solution once you got it..

Comment: We implement the solution for this ..

Comment: great.. is it open-source??

Comment: Sorry @enter its not open source we create it for internal use..but i can tell the approach that we r using to develop this framework..

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented keyword driven framework using protractor and jasmin. I didn't include the common functions which are required but the architecture wise i have done. Need to enhance more. Take a look at the below repository

https://github.com/mannejkumar/protractor-keyword-driven-framework